# Demonstrate immutability in an Ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, immutability

I am currently using a private Ethereum setup with 3 nodes. As part of the demo of my project, I need to demonstrate that Ethereum is immutable.

How do I show it using geth?

The audience of my project also includes many people not involved in technical side. How do I demonstrate immutability of Blockchain to them?

Comment: Try checking out the first video on this site: https://anders.com/blockchain/